# Feature class, Inspection Table and Defect table - Relationship Classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class

I have a file geodatabase with three elements in it.

1. Lighting layer (assets) consisting of point items.
2. Inspection table (containing inspection information for those assets)
3. Defects Table (linked to inspection table as parent/child and also need to be linked to the assets pulling in a range of data from the asset attributes)

My question is how to do this properly? I need the relationship classes set up so a defect can't exist without selecting its inspection record, and to create a defect the user must create it from an asset so it can pull in a variety of data automatically from the asset layer to auto populate some of the defect fields.

How would I go about setting up those relationship classes to give me the desired outcomes?

Work flow required would be:

- User creates inspection record (populates data)
- User clicks asset to create defect record, some data auto populates the rest he/she fills in.